# Basic Java : Error : Class, Interface, or Enum expected

Tags: java

I have this Java program which causes [these errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKrrp.jpg) to be thrown.

Here is the source code:

```
public class RcvThread2 implements Runnable {
private static final int sizeBuf = 50;
private Socket clientSocket;
private Logger logger;
private SocketAddress clientAddress; }

public RcvThread2(Socket clntSocket, SocketAddress clientAddress, Logger logger) {
this.clientSocket = clntSocket;
this.logger = logger;
this.clientAddress = clientAddress; }
```

Comment: You closed your class prematurely - `...private SocketAddress clientAddress; }`

Comment: the constructor isn't placed inside the class

Answer (score 1):

Remove the closing curly bracket after you declared `clientAddress`.

Otherwise your constructor declaration won't compile.

Add an additional closing curly bracket at the very end.

Answer (score 1):

Make the below changes

```
public class RcvThread2 implements Runnable {
    private static final int sizeBuf = 50;
    private Socket clientSocket;
    private Logger logger;
    private SocketAddress clientAddress;

    public RcvThread2(Socket clntSocket, SocketAddress clientAddress,
        Logger logger) {
        this.clientSocket = clntSocket;
        this.logger = logger;
        this.clientAddress = clientAddress;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

The issue was with the incorrect placing of `}` with variable declaration since the body of the class was getting closed there. Also implemented `Runnable` interface and run method was not overridden, so we need to override the run() method as well.

Comment: @Poisonshirimp can you evaluate both the answers and mark the correct answer from your end